# How do I get my website to look the same on mobile as it does in a resized Google Chrome Window?

Tags: visual-web-developer

I had to adapt an HTML website to run on MediaWiki. The website is here at http://2016.igem.org/Team:UrbanTundra_Edmonton . There were many bugs at first, as MediaWiki basically confines you into a text editor to do all your work, versus just having .HTML files on a server. However, I was able to fix most of the bugs. The only, and perhaps most crippling bug is the responsiveness of the website.

For example, if you resize the website in a Google Chrome window, the website behaves and looks fine. However, when you open the same website on a mobile phone, the nav-toggle moves off screen, and the general layout falls apart. Viewing the website through the different mediums will give a better understanding compared to my lackluster description.

This was actually a bigger issue before I decided to come here for help. I basically used 'Inspect Element' in Chrome to change a bunch of padding and margin values to get everything looking nice. And truly, in a resized Chrome window, it looks fine.

Then I tried using Chrome's mobile emulator (that's built into the Dev Tools) and using my trial and error method to no avail.

I was wondering if anyone could help me out, or at least give me some tips on how I could take was is seen on a resized Chrome window, and display that on mobile?

Comment: Do you have a meta viewport tag?

Comment: Yes I do. In fact, I initially did not have one, and was facing many issues. After adding it, a lot of issues were fixed in terms of responsiveness. Did you take a look at the website in a reisized Chrome window vs a mobile phone?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer! My meta tag read like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I actually just had to add the user-scalable parameter and set it to no! So know it reads like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Now everything works like intended!